# can we add virtual scrolling on React Kendo Grid Wrapper

Tags: reactjs, scroll, grid, wrapper, virtual

Is it possible to add virtual scrolling on React Kendo Grid Wrapper, If yes can you please share a sample code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by setting the scrolling property to virtual:

```
scrollable={{ virtual: true}}
```

It also requires a pageSize to be set.